# Opencart v2.3, Contact us form passes without authenticating google captcha. When we press the submit button it doesn't ask for captcha

Tags: opencart, captcha, recaptcha

It is client side integration. This is my website www.festivetaste.com
Even the basic catcha is not showing up.

[Link for Contact us page](https://www.festivetaste.com/index.php?route=information/contact)

following is the code from the contact.tpl file.

```
 <form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo $text_contact; ?></legend>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-name"><?php echo $entry_name; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" id="input-name" class="form-control" />
          <?php if ($error_name) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_name; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-email"><?php echo $entry_email; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" id="input-email" class="form-control" />
          <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_email; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="input-enquiry"><?php echo $entry_enquiry; ?></label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
          <textarea name="enquiry" rows="10" id="input-enquiry" class="form-control"><?php echo $enquiry; ?></textarea>
          <?php if ($error_enquiry) { ?>
          <div class="text-danger"><?php echo $error_enquiry; ?></div>
          <?php } ?>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo $captcha; ?>
    </fieldset>

    <div class="buttons">
      <div class="pull-right">
      <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcivgwUAAAAADYVi7N2X7sQ1d29Wl1jnJfntQha"></div>
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="<?php echo $button_submit; ?>" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: Which Opencart version?

Comment: I am using opencart version 2.3

Comment: Did you try default captcha?

Comment: I enable the default captcha, but I do not see it on registration, review, contact us page.

Comment: Currently I have uninstalled Google captcha, Basic captcha is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Catalog/controller/Extension/captcha/basic-captcha.php
Find `$this->session->data['captcha'] = substr(sha1(mt_rand()), 17, 6);`

place this code after it.

```
// Editted by Foundlay 
    $out = ob_get_contents();
    $out = str_replace(array("\n", "\r", "\t", " "), "",$this->session->data['captcha']);
    ob_end_clean();
    $this->session->data['captcha'] = $out;
```

This is only for opencart 2.3.* version.

Comment: ooh!  this is for inbuilt captcha in OC. `basic-captcha`.